# Can I assign a singleton to use a separate thread in obj-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I wrote a singleton object using obj-c, and which is a dataConnector. It will receive and send data between server. But I would like to separate this dataConnector into a dedicate thread, which is not affect others in the application. Because, some time, I would like to the singleton can sleep, within affecting others. Is this possible for me to do so? If not, what can I do? Thanks.

Comment: The threads would be for sending and receiving, your singleton would manage them...

Comment: A singleton is (handle for) a data object.  It need not have any "real" methods associated with it at all.  What you do with it is up to you.  (And singletons tend to be grossly overused by novices -- you probably don't need one.)

Answer (score 0):

The singleton is just the manager of the data and it runs in the thread in which is called.
It seems you are a bit confused about the threading, so I suggest you to read a tutorial like:
http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.cocoa.php